# SCP QGIS Training input is not loading?

Tags: qgis, error, classification, scp, input

I am using QGIS, version 3.10.14 and the semi-classification plugin and want to create a training input, to classify different land-use-types. I followed the manual (https://readthedocs.org/projects/semiautomaticclassificationmanual-de/downloads/pdf/latest/, page 163).

When I define a training input, it does not appear in the line within the SCP Dock.

When I try to save my classes, I get the following error:

> Information [3]: Select a SCP training input; input is not loaded

This question has already been asked, but there was no answer. How can I define the training input?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the temporary directory and saved my training input on the same drive.

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, you have to creat a new training input, its a white icon with a yellow dot, click there and choose a name for the file, click in save, and then you can just start saving your class with no problems.